# In EnvDTE's Debugger.GetExpression method, what does "UseAutoExpandRules" mean exactly?

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, envdte, vs-extensibility

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1x8ehx%28VS.90%29.aspx) poignantly explains that this parameter should be "true if the auto-expand rules should be used; otherwise, false.", but what does it mean exactly?

I can't seem to find any explanation online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer - the parameter refers to the autoexp.dat file under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\" (or the autoexp.cs equivalent for .NET), which automatically expand items in Watch and DataTips to show the most important items.